# Trying to update an App.config value based on a Jenkins parameterized build selection

Tags: c#, jenkins, nunit

So, like the title suggests, I've got a jenkins build / job that I'm wanting to parameterize with different options for the different environments that it could be executed against (dev, qa, cert, stage, prod, etc.). The 2nd part of what I'm wanting to accomplish is based on what the user selects from the environment dropdown (dev, qa, cert, etc.) it would then update the App.config file with that environment value so the same automation job could be ran in multiple environments for multiple deployment validations.

This is my first shot at creating my parameterized list:
[image]

And then, based on what option is selected, I would want to update the environment value in App.config with the selected value.

Here is what the App.config looks like (just basic xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Environment" value="QA" />
    <!--DEV is default value -->
    <!--
    DRIVER Parameters for installed web browsers
      C = Chrome
      CH = Headless Chrome
      F = Firefox
      E = Microsoft Edge
      IE = Internet Ex
    -->
    <add key="Browser" value="C" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I was playing around with some of the different options that jenkins provides for parameterized builds and reading some tutorials but nothing that directly answered my question. A lot of what I was finding was based around CI/CD and builds triggering other builds in different environments.

Any help is always appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is easy if you use a pipeline script. Is that an option for you?

Comment: I'm not sure what a pipeline script is so it's hard for me to say one way or another.

Comment: Here's some info about Jenkins Pipeline as Code https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/